# How do you add prefixes to routes? Rails (4.2.5) routing confusion.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have two controllers `offers` and `posts`.

In `routes.rb` I've got the following...

```
resources :offers

get "/posts"          => "posts#index"
post "/posts"         => "posts#create"
get "/posts/new"      => "posts#new"
get "/posts/:id/edit" => "posts#edit"
get "/posts/:id"      => "posts#show"
put "/posts/:id"      => "posts#update"  
patch "/posts/:id"    => "posts#update"   
delete "/posts/:id"   => "posts#destroy"
```

It was my understanding that these two ways of doing the routing are identical in their operation. Or put another way `resources :offers` is a just shortcut for writing out each route.

My problem however is when I do a `rake routes` I get...

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    offers GET    /offers(.:format)          offers#index
           POST   /offers(.:format)          offers#create
 new_offer GET    /offers/new(.:format)      offers#new
edit_offer GET    /offers/:id/edit(.:format) offers#edit
     offer GET    /offers/:id(.:format)      offers#show
           PATCH  /offers/:id(.:format)      offers#update
           PUT    /offers/:id(.:format)      offers#update
           DELETE /offers/:id(.:format)      offers#destroy
     posts GET    /posts(.:format)           posts#index
           POST   /posts(.:format)           posts#create
 posts_new GET    /posts/new(.:format)       posts#new
           GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)  posts#edit
           GET    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#show
           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
           PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#update
           DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)       posts#destroy
```

The 'shorthand' `offers` routes have a four prefixes assigned to them, whereas the longhand `posts` routes have only two.

So my questions are: 
Why don't all the routes get given prefixes when written out longhand?

Is there any way of assigning a prefix to a route when writing them out longhand?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a prefix to a route when writing them out longhand by doing:

`root 'pages#index', as: :home`, where `:home` is your prefix.

Source:
[Generating Paths and URLs from Code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code)